# Validar que ya existe usuario registrado C# y MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, mvc

estoy realizando una aplicación web donde estoy manejando inicios de sesión y registro de usuarios. Todo esta bien salvo que intento hacer que la aplicación verifique y detecte que ya existe un usuario que se haya registrado previamente. Para el usuario utilizo la matricula del alumno.

Estoy utilizando Ajax, Json y C# MVC.

Dejo a continuación los fragmentos de código.

HTML

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="registroForm">
                    <label class="etiqueta1">Nombre</label><br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control espacios" name="txtnombre" id="txtnombre" required /><br />
                    <label class="etiqueta1">Apellido Paterno</label><br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control espacios" name="txtappaterno" id="txtappaterno" required /><br />
                    <label class="etiqueta1">Apellido Materno</label><br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control espacios" name="txtapmaterno" id="txtapmaterno" required /><br />
                    <label class="etiqueta1">Matricula</label><br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control espacios" name="txtmatricula" id="txtmatricula" required maxlength="10" /><br />
                    <label class="etiqueta1">Contraseña</label><br />
                    <input type="password" class="form-control espacios" name="txtpasswordR" id="txtpasswordR" required maxlength="10" /><br />
                    <label class="etiqueta1">Confirmar contraseña</label><br />
                    <input type="password" class="form-control espacios" name="txtpass" id="txtpass" required maxlength="10" /><br />
                </form>
```

Ajax y Json

```
function RegistrarDatos() {
var nombre = $('#txtnombre').val();
var appaterno = $('#txtappaterno').val();
var apmaterno = $('#txtapmaterno').val();
var matricula = $('#txtmatricula').val();
var pass = $('#txtpasswordR').val();
var spass = $('#txtpass').val();

if (pass == spass) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../Home/RegistrarDatos",
        data: "{'nombre': '" + nombre + "', 'apellidoPaterno': '" + appaterno + "', 'apellidoMaterno': '" + apmaterno + "', 'matricula': '" + matricula + "', 'contraseña': '" + pass + "'}",
        async: false,
        content: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        error: function (xhr) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'ERROR...',
                text: 'ERROR EN LA COMUNICACIÓN CON EL CONTROLADOR'
            })
        },
        success: function (result) {
            switch (result) {
                case "1":
                    $('#registroForm')[0].reset();
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'REGISTRO EXITOSO',
                        text: 'LOS DATOS SE HAN ENVIADO CORRECTAMENTE, YA PUEDES INICIAR SESIÓN'
                    })
                    break;
                case "2":
                    $('#registroForm')[0].reset();
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'ERROR...',
                        text: 'ERROR EN EL INSERT, LOS DATOS NO SE HAN ENVIADO'
                    })
                    break;
                case "3":
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'warning',
                        title: 'ADVERTENCIA',
                        text: 'UNO O MAS CAMPOS NO HAN SIDO LLENADOS, VERIFICA TODOS LOS CAMPOS'
                    })
                    break;
                case "4":
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'ERROR...',
                        text: 'LA MATRICULA YA FUE REGISTRADA'
                    })
                    break;
            }
        }
    })
}
```

C# MVC

```
        public JsonResult RegistrarDatos(string nombre, string apellidoPaterno, string apellidoMaterno, string matricula, string contraseña)
    {
        if (nombre != "" && apellidoPaterno != "" && apellidoMaterno != "" && matricula != "" && contraseña != "")
        {
            int valor = db.insertar("INSERT INTO Tbl_Usuarios (nombre,apellidoPaterno,apellidoMaterno,matricula,contraseña,privilegio) VALUES('"+nombre+"', '"+apellidoPaterno+"', '"+apellidoMaterno+"', '"+matricula +"', '"+contraseña+"', '"+3+"')");
            
            if(valor == 1)
            {
                return Json("1", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("2", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("3", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Es el fragmento de código que estoy utilizando.
La idea es que cuando el usuario introduzca una matricula ya registrada esta arroje un mensaje o alerta de que la matricula ya esta registrada y que debe utilizar otra diferente.

Agradecería su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Y por qué no haces un select primero? Busca el usuario primero, y si no existe, continúas con el insert

Comment: Primero has una consulta con la matricula que desees saber si existe o no, y dependiendo de la respuesta, insertas o no.